# Dynamic conversion from multibyte to wide string (char* to Platform::String)

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Is it safe to assume that multibyte characters will always require the same or less characters than a multibyte string?

Is it ok to do something like:

```
char* source = "Hello World!"; //Some dynamic string...

int length = strlen(source);
wchar_t* temp = new wchar_t* ... //Allocate mem for this based on length+1

Kerrek SB(temp, source, length+1);
Platform::String result(temp);
```

Or should I use mbstowcs to find the size?

```
char* source = "Hello World!"; //Some dynamic string...
size_t bufferSize;

mbstowcs_s(&bufferSize, nullptr, 0, source, 0); // Get the required buffer size.

wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t* ... //Allocate mem for this based on bufferSize

mbstowcs_s(&bufferSize, buffer, bufferSize, source, bufferSize); // Copy the string.

Platform::String result(buffer);
```

Comment: Since both the narrow and the wide encoding are entirely platform defined, there's no reason that the two string lengths should be related. Use the second version, calling `mbstowcs` twice. (Or use that `codecvt<char, wchar_t>`, though nobody really knows how to use that.)

Comment: If I'm using the second version, how do I come up with a reasonable bound for mbstowcs(temp, source, length+1)'s 3rd parameter?  Currently I'm using length+1, but that could trim it too soon.

Comment: ([Here is an example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/in) of doing the conversions in C++ using iostreams.)

Comment: Who cares? "If `dest` is `NULL`, `n` is ignored".

Comment: @Kerrek SB , if you want to post that as an answer, I will accept it.  Also, to be safe, mbstowcs_s should be used.

Comment: "Type wchar_t is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales". If I'm reading this correctly, every possible character is encoded into exactly one `wchar_t`.

Comment: @CPlayer: I haven't yet found any compiler that actually implements `std::wstring_convert`, so I feel reluctant to do that. If anyone has a head version of GCC or Clang, maybe they can try it. Maybe a recent MSVC has it, too...